# Google Crawling/Indexing Frequency Increasing?

Tags: seo, googlebot

Sometime ago google used to update their index and backlinks every 3-4 months. It used to be a big update. Recently I noticed that the updates are way too frequent. has anyone else noticed these sort of changes in Google crawling, indexing and backlink updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's crawling algorithms are constantly changing and evolving. Most of the sites I monitor get their sitemaps pinged by Google everyday, occasionally even multiple times per day. And that's been true for a few years.

Many factors play into how google indexes your site, and how often. Whether you use webmaster tools, what your sitemap defines for your change frequency, whether or not you use analytics, your PageRank, etc...

While I will say that the frequency has gone up somewhat over the past few years I haven't seen any substantial leaps lately. Nothing to be concerned about, unless you're trying to game the system, in which case Google will catch you. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am not trying to game the system. I need to start a project that requires some tough deadlines and i wanted to know the affect of the changes in relation to my project. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on Google "trust" to website.